# use class on textbox to use plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

is it possible i use jquery plugin on class which is assigned to a textbox
i mean this

```
<input type='text' size='3' class='abc'>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.myClass').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: why not try it? http://jsfiddle.net/jttQB/1/

Comment: actually your code isn't working, as you are applying `class="abc"` to the input and selecting `.myClass` in your script ...

Comment: Considering you've already had the code ready wouldn't it be easier to just test it yourself rather than post it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure ..

```
$(".myClass").Something ..
```

---

http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it , you can apply the pugin.

here is the example : example : http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/11/jquery-plugin-how-and-when-to-use-it.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes it ought to be.

The `$()` will return a collection of jQuery objects. It doesn't matter if the selector iside is an #id, element, .class or :pseudoclass selector.